# Pandas, concatenating values of columns.

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, unary-operator

I have found answers to this question on here before, but none of them seem to work for me. Right now I have a data frame with a list of clients and their address. However, each address is separated into many columns and i'm trying to put them all under one.

The code I have so far read as so:

```
data1_df['Address'] = data1_df['Address 1'].map(str) + ", " + data1_df['Address 2'].map(str) + ", " +  data1_df['Address 3'].map(str) + ", " + data1_df['city'].map(str) + ", " +  data1_df['city'].map(str) + ", " +  data1_df['Province/State'].map(str) + ", " +  data1_df['Country'].map(str) + ", " +  data1_df['Postal Code'].map(str)
```

However, the error I get is:
   TypeError: Unary plus expects numeric dtype, not object

I'm not sure why it's not accepting the strings as they are and using the + operator. Shouldn't the plus accommodate objects?

Comment: Are any of your columns missing data? This can be quite annoying and leads to multiple `', '` characters between non-missing fields with your approach

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you so much for helping, but an answer was found.

Comment: @ALollz The solution that was presented worked for me despite this. However, you're correct in a way because i have NANs showing up in the new column in specific places. I wonder how I can get around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully you'll find this example helpful:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3],
                   'B': list('ABC'),
                   'C': [4,5,np.nan],
                   'D': ['One', np.nan, 'Three']})

addColumns = ['B', 'C', 'D']

df['Address'] = df[addColumns].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i for i in x if i != 'nan']), axis=1)

df

#   A  B    C      D      Address
#0  1  A  4.0    One  A, 4.0, One
#1  2  B  5.0    NaN       B, 5.0
#2  3  C  NaN  Three     C, Three
```

The above will work as `str` representation of `NaN` is `nan`.

Or you can make it with filling `NaN` with empty strings:

```
df['Address'] = df[addColumns].fillna('').astype(str).apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i for i in x if i]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can get around the cases where there are NAN values in certain columns. I mean to exclude those from the actual concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of columns with `NaN` values that you need to add together, here's some logic:

```
def add_cols_w_nan(df, col_list, space_char, new_col_name):
    """ Add together multiple columns where some of the columns 
    may contain NaN, with the appropriate amount of spacing between columns. 

    Examples:
        'Mr.' + NaN + 'Smith' becomes 'Mr. Smith'
        'Mrs.' + 'J.' + 'Smith' becomes 'Mrs. J. Smith'
        NaN + 'J.' + 'Smith' becomes 'J. Smith'

    Args:
        df: pd.DataFrame
            DataFrame for which strings are added together.
        col_list: ORDERED list of column names, eg. ['first_name', 
            'middle_name', 'last_name']. The columns will be added in order. 
        space_char: str
            Character to insert between concatenation of columns.
        new_col_name: str
            Name of the new column after adding together strings.

    Returns: pd.DataFrame with a string addition column

    """
    df2 = df[col_list].copy()

    # Convert to strings, leave nulls alone
    df2 = df2.where(df2.isnull(), df2.astype('str'))

    # Add space character, NaN remains NaN, which is important
    df2.loc[:, col_list[1:]] = space_char + df2.loc[:, col_list[1:]]

    # Fix rows where leading columns are null
    to_fix = df2.notnull().idxmax(1)
    for col in col_list[1:]:
        m = to_fix == col
        df2.loc[m, col] = df2.loc[m, col].str.replace(space_char, '')

    # So that summation works
    df2[col_list] = df2[col_list].replace(np.NaN, '')

    # Add together all columns
    df[new_col_name] = df2[col_list].sum(axis=1)
    # If all are missing replace with missing
    df[new_col_name] = df[new_col_name].replace('', np.NaN)

    del df2
    return df
```

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address 1': ['AAA', 'ABC', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'Address 2': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', None, np.NaN],
                   'Address 3': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 17, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'city': [np.NaN, 'here', 'there', 'anywhere', np.NaN],
                   'state': ['NY', 'TX', 'WA', 'MI', np.NaN]})

#  Address 1 Address 2  Address 3      city state
#0       AAA       foo        NaN       NaN    NY
#1       ABC       bar        NaN      here    TX
#2       NaN       baz       17.0     there    WA
#3       NaN      None        NaN  anywhere    MI
#4       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN

df = add_cols_w_nan(
    df,
    col_list = ['Address 1', 'Address 2', 'Address 3', 'city', 'state'],
    space_char = ', ',
    new_col_name = 'full_address')

df.full_address.tolist()
#['AAA, foo, NY', 
# 'ABC, bar, here, TX', 
# 'baz, 17.0, there, WA', 
# 'anywhere, MI',
# nan]
```